# Jquery validation for radio box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

May i know how can i do validation for radio button in jquery? I need user to select items from the radio list, if none of the items is select when they submit the form the system will shows the error message at label. Any helps would be appreciated.

Please check the jsfiddle for sample.

Jsfiddle :`1` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvETA/78/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/VvETA/81/)**

> `id`s must be always unique in the `DOM` so `input type="radio"`
>   cannot have duplicate `id`s

Instead I have added a class to your `radio` button and below will be the reflection of the same:

```
<input class="rds" type="radio" name="SUBCLS" id="SUBCLS" value="CO" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" style="vertical-align: -2px;" />Comprehensive
<input class="rds" type="radio" name="SUBCLS" value="TF" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Third Party Fire &amp; Theft
<input class="rds" type="radio" name="SUBCLS" value="TP" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />Third Party
<div class="errmsg"></div> <!--A div to display error message-->
```

in your `fnValidate()`

```
if(!$(".rds:checked").length)
{
      $(".errmsg").text('Please select a value from radio')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$("[name=SUBCLS]:checked").length`

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function (e) {
    if (!$("[name=SUBCLS]:checked").length || $.trim($("#VEHNO").val()) == '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#optionalerrMsg").show();
    }else{
         $("#optionalerrMsg").hide();
    }

});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VvETA/85/)**

Comment: Hi, thx it's worked for radiobox! But how to combine validation for both textbox and radiobox

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `$("[name='SUBCLS']").is(":checked")`
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function (e) {
        var res = $("[name='SUBCLS']");
        if (!res.is(":checked")) {
            fnValidate();
        }
    });
});
```